# Торт - сладкое, а лимон - кислое

Tags: стилистика

Можно ли так сказать? "Торт - сладкое, а лимон - кислое". Или это будет ошибкой?

Answer (score 3):

Если СЛАДКОЕ и КИСЛОЕ в Вашем примере - это существительные (субст.прилагательные), то предложение построено правильно. Если же прилагательные, то права Fuchoin Kazuki. Если, говоря СЛАДКОЕ, вы имели в виду блюдо, то нужно внимать ответу Виктора.
 Ваше предложение вполне уместно, когда кому-то объясняют, что такое сладкое, что такое кислое. Например, детям в детском саду. Торт и лимон, предположим, оказались среди прочих примеров сладкого и кислого.  Конфеты, торт, сахар -  сладкое, лимон, клюква -  кислое.

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем ясен вопрос, но могу предположить, что речь идет о блюдах.Так сложилось, что блюда называют так: "холодные закуски, горячие закуски, первое,горячее, сладкое..."Обычно под "сладким" понимают кондитерские изделия, конфеты, пирожные, торты и т.п. Понятие "кислое" никогда не встречал. Обычно лимоны и др. объединяются названием блюда "фрукты"

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, все-таки уместнее будет сказать "сладкий" и "кислый". Во-первых, оба существительных мужского рода, во-вторых, вкус — сладкий и кислый, а в-третьих, в русском языке по умолчанию принят мужской род.

Answer (score 2):

А о какой, простите, вообще ошибке может идти речь?
Стилистическа - ну это контекст надо смотреть, грамматической я тут не вижу, сочетаемость - неприменимо, тут вообще нет сочетаний...

Едиственное, о чем можно, пожалуй, говорить - так это о возможной двусмысленности. Сладкое - обозначение блюда в списке подаваемых, оно же - десерт. "Кислое" такого не предполагает. Если торт - сладкое именно в этом смысле, то фраза становится нарочито парадоксальной, но от того не менее правильной.

Ну а если это из учебника по кулинарии или (в порядке бреда) о физиологии вкуса и вкусовых рецепторах, то никаких сомнений вообще нет.